# Are both correct: "Having greeted you" and "Greeting you"?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, negation, perfect-aspect

Is it correct to say:

1. I apologize for not **having greeted** you when you visited my house last month.

Or is it only correct to say:

2. I apologize for not **greeting** you when you visited my house last month?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If, as I suspect, you are not a native English speaker, I would advise you to ask questions like this on our sister site English Language Learners. @tchrist, one of our moderators, clearly thinks your question does fit the site, but I find — at least in British English — the use of the word greet to be unnatural or at least overly formal. In my opinion the place where it is appropriate to explain this is not here but on ELL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are both just fine.

We would normally avoid the longer formulation unless some emphasis were being placed on the completed nature of the missed greeting, but there's nothing wrong with either of those.

Comment: You would have to use "not having Xed" when talking about something not done ahead of time, e.g. "I apologise for not having packed my bag when you arrived" means "I should have packed before you came but I did not". But without that sort of time relationship, in the fast majority of cases Xed and Xing would have the same meaning.

Comment: With all due respect (and that is meant honestly) I do think your answer is just an expression of opinion. My own opinion is that this is incorrect as nobody I know would ever employ the verb "greet" in this way except when addressing royalty. People would use different constructions using the less precise verb, "meet" — e.g. "I'm sorry I wasn't there to meet you when…" And "visited my house" sounds like something out of an English learners book. "Came round", "were here" or whatever fits. But perhaps Americans are more formal than us relaxed Brits.

Comment: @David You're perfectly correct. It does sound laughably formal, doesn't it?

Comment: Often difficult to switch from academic mode to vernacular mode. It struck me later that an even more natural thing to say would be "I'm sorry I wasn't here/there to **welcome** you".